# Separator in a Wicket DropDownChoice

Tags: java, drop-down-menu, wicket

Is there some obvious way to add a separator to the list of options in a Wicket DropDownChoice? In my case I'm populating the selection with two types of domain objects from my datasource. I guess I could go and manually add some kind of dummy domain object to the choice list but it feels pretty ugly.

Example:

```
+---------+-+
| Apple   |▼|
| Orange  +-+
| ------- |
| Carrot  |
| Cucumber|
+---------+
```

Current code (without any separator) looks something like:

```
EntityModel model = getModel();
List<? extends Produce> foods = foodService.getAllProduce(); 
// getAllProduce() returns first all fruits, then all vegetables
add(new DropDownChoice<Produce>(
    "produceSelect", new PropertyModel<Produce>(model, "favProduce"), foods)
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples-6.0.x/compref/wicket/bookmarkable/org.apache.wicket.examples.compref.SelectPage
There is "Source code" link.

Comment: I used this as the solution, see the detailed description below in my answer.

Comment: I'd love to see an updated link if there is one.  Otherwise, I'm not sure this answer is still valid and should probably be deleted.

Comment: @spaaarky21 maybe [this](http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/compref/wicket/bookmarkable/org.apache.wicket.examples.compref.SelectPage)?

Answer (score 7):

I ended up solving this using the `Select` and `SelectOptions` components from [wicket-extensions](http://www.wicketframework.org/wicket-extensions/index.html) as mentioned by martin-g.

```
SelectOptions<Produce> fruitOptions = new SelectOptions<Produce>(
                                      "fruits",
                                      fruitCollection, 
                                      new FruitRenderer());

SelectOptions<Produce> vegetableOptions = new SelectOptions<Produce>(
                                          "vegetables",
                                          vegetableCollection, 
                                          new VegetableRenderer());

Select select = new Select("produceSelect", 
                           new PropertyModel<Produce>(model, "favProduce"));
select.add(fruitOptions);
select.add(vegetableOptions);
```

The corresponding HTML looks something like this:

```
<select wicket:id="produceSelect" id="produceSelect">
    <optgroup label="Fruits">
        <wicket:container wicket:id="fruits">
            <option wicket:id="option">Apple</option>
        </wicket:container>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Vegetables">
        <wicket:container wicket:id="vegetables">
            <option wicket:id="option">Carrot</option>
        </wicket:container>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

This produces a bit different but better end result as the `optgroup` labels are bolded and cannot be selected:

```
+----------------+-+
| **Fruits**     |▼|
| Apple          +-+  
| Orange         | 
| **Vegetables** |  
| Carrot         |
| Cucumber       |
+----------------+
```

Comment: This solution assumes that you know that the groups will be 'fruits' and 'Vegetables' . What if you dont know the expected groups?

Comment: In that case, you will not be able to use a SelectOption in this way since under the hood it is just a repeatingListView that needs to have an ID. You might want to create a repeating listviewe directly under the select that in turn contains a SelectOption with a fixed ID?

Answer (score 5):

```
    add(new DropDownChoice<String>("choice", Arrays.asList("Apple","Orange","Carrot","Cucumber")) {
        @Override
        protected void appendOptionHtml(AppendingStringBuffer buffer, String choice, int index, String selected) {
            super.appendOptionHtml(buffer, choice, index, selected);
            if ("Orange".equals(choice)) {
                buffer.append("<optgroup label='----------'></optgroup>");
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thing is, PropertyModel is used for a good reason (UI changes propagate nice & automatically down to persistence layer). This approach (giving DropDownChoice simply a list of choices) would complicate how domain objects (& database) get updated.

Comment: Er, what? The example is about how to add the separator (overriding `appendOptionHtml()` and appending `<optgroup>`). Passing a list directly was just the simplest thing I could do to make the example to compile and run. Of course you could use the `PropertyModel` and custom classes...

Comment: Ah, sorry, I somehow missed your point (overriding appendOptionHtml()). This would indeed work with PropertyModel just as well. You'd just have to figure out which is the *last* domain object of the *first* type (or first of the second type, which I guess would be easier). So, +1 as this is a viable solution that's at least quicker than switching to Select & SelectOptions from wicket-extensions.

Comment: Doesn't this have the problem it will not enclose the `<option>` tags inside an `<optgroup>`? The `<option>` tags should be children of the `<optgroup>`.

Comment: Well, the more 'semantically correct' way to do this is using the Select/SelectOption components, as pointed by @martin-g. The `appendOptionHtml()` is a simple hack that may come handy in some situations. By 'hack' I don't mean it'll generate invalid HTML (by itself) or cause any trouble to Wicket, but is not a pure and, again, 'semantically correct' HTML (since the option elements are not grouped by their semantics). But may take fewer lines :)