# How to remove a validator from a Select?

Tags: wicket, validation

I have a form where I need to add/remove validators dynamically. Based on a dropdown selection, other form fields may have different validation rules.

For other kinds of inputs, I've used `replace(methodThatCreatesTheInput())` to get rid of a previously added validator. (Not knowing of a better way. Specifically, there doesn't seem to be any way to directly remove a validator from a component...)

With **[Select](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/extensions/markup/html/form/select/Select.html)**, from wicket-extensions, this approach fails with something like:

```
WicketMessage: submitted http post value [[Ljava.lang.String;@5b4bf56d] 
for SelectOption component  [8:myForm:targetInput] contains an 
illegal relative path element [targetConsortiums:1:option] which does not
point to an SelectOption component. Due to this the Select component cannot 
resolve the selected SelectOption component pointed to by the illegal value.
A possible reason is that component hierarchy changed between rendering and 
form submission.
```

The method that creates the Select:

```
private FormComponent<?> targetSelection() {
    Map<Class<? extends Target>, List<Target>> targets = targetService.getAllAsMap();

    SelectOptions<Target> propertyOptions = new SelectOptions<Target>("targetConsortiums",
            targets.get(Consortium.class), new TargetRenderer());
    SelectOptions<Target> consortiumOptions = new SelectOptions<Target>("targetProperties",
            targets.get(Property.class), new TargetRenderer());

    Select select = new Select(ID_TARGET, new PropertyModel<Target>(model, "target"));
    select.add(propertyOptions);
    select.add(consortiumOptions);
    select.setRequired(true);
    select.setMarkupId(ID_TARGET);

    return select;
}
```

(Why use a Select instead of normal DropDownChoice? We want the two types of choices to be clearly separated, [as documented in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6592893/56285).)

**Any ideas how to solve this?** What I'm trying to achieve is, of course, very simple. Unfortunately Wicket disagrees, or I'm using it wrong.

Wicket 1.4.

Comment: I came up with a relatively easy workaround: use **form validator** that considers the values of both inputs (in my case "loan type" and "loan target" selections) and never needs to be removed from the form. I won't spend more time on this, but feel free to answer the original question if you can!

Comment: I think form validators are not just a workaround, they're the correct answer. They are specifically there to deal with validation involving more than one input value.

Comment: @biziclop, thanks! If you want to add that as an answer, maybe elaborated slightly, I'd accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do this on Wicket 1.4, but on Wicket 1.5 there is a remove method for validators on FormComponent (see [javadoc](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.5/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/FormComponent.html#remove%28org.apache.wicket.validation.IValidator%29))

Comment: Yeah, [1.4 doesn't have](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/FormComponent.html) such method; that was the problem.