# Wicket Dropdown with Autocomplete and Categories

Tags: jquery, html, wicket

I need an autocomplete with a dropdown with results categorised like in HTML select - optgroup with keyboard navigation.

I tried to implement a wicket Select component with groups  based on this: [Separator in a Wicket DropDownChoice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592893/separator-in-a-wicket-dropdownchoice) with a textfield for search, but can't jump to select with "Arrow down".

Any other ideas?

Comment: Found a jQuery example: http://jsfiddle.net/gB32r/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you best option is Select2 (example: https://select2.github.io/examples.html#themes-templating-responsive-design) and its Wicket integration: https://github.com/wicketstuff/core/tree/master/select2-parent

Comment: I cannot add groups to options in Wicket, and no example found. Select 2 knows only autocomplete with single/multi select. Any other solutions?

Comment: To use <optgroup> in Wicket you can use Wicket-Extensions Select component. Demo at: http://examples7x.wicket.apache.org/compref/wicket/bookmarkable/org.apache.wicket.examples.compref.SelectPage. It should be easy to integrate it with Select2 JS widget.

Comment: Be aware that Select2 has not traditionally been very WCAG compliant for screen readers so if that is a requirement be sure to test it. Not sure about later versions of it.